# Intersection Between two tables, one Empty- SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do intersection Between two tables with a **different scheme**, it isnt legal.
but, what if one table are empty?.
What is the result?
it is also not legal or that equals to empty table?

Comment: The intersection with an empty set is the empty set.

Comment: Is this prior to illegality?

Comment: I mean somthing like that; one table is A(x,y) and it's empty, intersection with B(x).

Comment: An empty set is a legal result. Not an error.